# Inifinite loop makes variable come out as 0

Tags: c++

I have this piece of code in my school book.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int x=10,c=1;
  while (c < 5) {
    x += x*c;
    c *= 2;
    c++;
    c -= 2;
    cout << "X=" << x<<'\n';
  }
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

As you can see it's an infinite loop, when logically traced, it should show 20,40,80 and so on.
However it always shows 0.
when adding system("pause") after each loop cycle it shows the correct values, but when left as shown above (infinitely looping) it shows zero.
Any ideas of the reason?

Comment: The loop becomes infinite.that causes `x` to overflow, which makes it to become `0`.(note that integer overflow **always** results in `0`)

Comment: @SLY: Signed integer overflow is technically undefined behavior. But disregarding that, it certainly does not always result in 0.

Answer (score 11):

`c` is always 1 no matter what. The loop becomes infinite. Eventually, `X` becomes `0` due to integer overflow.

```
c = 1
c *= 2; c = 2
c++; c = 3
c -= 2; c = 1 <-- infinite
```

Comment: Thank you :)
didn't know integer overflow results in zero

Comment: John Grant did state that it is an infinite loop, in the question.The issue is different than overflow.  (He says it is always 0, not just eventually).

Comment: @donjuedo What is the issue, then? It's apparent that by "always 0", he meant all that he could see. The first few outputs of the function are pushed off the stdout buffer nearly instantly, at the rate modern CPUs work.

Comment: @JohnGrant He didn't say it's always 0. He said it becomes 0 when left to loop infinitely. I don't think he had the patience to sit and watch those numbers scroll for 10 minutes until finally rolling over.

Comment: @CareyGregory, This part: "However it always shows 0"

Comment: @donjuedo His choice of words was incorrect, but since he did not understand the cause of the problem, there was no way for him to know that. What he actually meant is obvious (see mgrant's answer).

Comment: Could you add a more detailed explanation of why exactly `x` eventually resolves to 0?

Comment: @John: Signed integer overflow results in undefined behavior; anything could happen. Typical behavior is that it acts like modular arithmetic (i.e. only the least significant bits of the result are retained), but that's not reliable. (unsigned integer overflow *is* reliable, though)

Comment: @RedRoboHood, Fair enough.  But I have dealt with buffer overruns, flushing, and lack of it, as well as other strange behavior.  So given what he did write, his intent was not at all obvious to me.

Comment: @Hurkyl Do you think this particular case is probably the result of padding bits?

Comment: @Red: No: I think we are seeing the modular arithmetic behavior I suggested. Repeated doubling sets all of the bits to zero.

Comment: @Hurkyl Ah, right. That was my original guess, but I must be getting tired; I misunderstood the code as adding 10 to `x` each iteration, not doubling it. Time to sleep, I guess...

Answer (score 4):

Here is my answer for your questions:

1. Why do you get infinitely looping?

   awesomeyi did answer you above, because the condition of the while loop is always true, so it is never ended.
2. Why does X always equal to 0?

Please pay your attention on X varable, its value will be increased after ending one loop x += x*c. Because you are in the infinitely loop, x's value will be increased forever until greater than the limited value of an integer variable. Then, the value will be set as zero. Please see my output when running your code.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Removing the pause doesn't cause it to *always* show zero.  It just prints output so quickly that zeroes are all you see at the bottom.  Add the pause back in and click through about 30-40 iterations and see if it helps you understand what is happening.